# Split list of names into alphabetic dictionary, in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

List.

```
['Chrome', 'Chromium', 'Google', 'Python']
```

Result.

```
{'C': ['Chrome', 'Chromium'], 'G': ['Google'], 'P': ['Python']}
```

I can make it work like this.

```
alphabet = dict()
for name in ['Chrome', 'Chromium', 'Google', 'Python']:
  character = name[:1].upper()
  if not character in alphabet:
    alphabet[character] = list()
  alphabet[character].append(name)
```

It is probably a bit faster to pre-populate the dictionary with A-Z, to save the key check on every name, and then afterwards delete keys with empty lists. I'm not sure either is the best solution though.

Is there a *pythonic* way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anything wrong with this? I agree with Antoine, the oneliner solution is rather cryptic.

```
import collections

alphabet = collections.defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
    alphabet[word[0].upper()].append(word)
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's Pythonic, but it's more succinct:

```
import itertools
def keyfunc(x):
   return x[:1].upper()
l = ['Chrome', 'Chromium', 'Google', 'Python']
l.sort(key=keyfunc)
dict((key, list(value)) for (key,value) in itertools.groupby(l, keyfunc))
```

*EDIT 2* made it less succinct than previous version, more readable and more correct (`groupby` works as intended only on sorted lists)

Comment: @Antoine: I hope not. The groupby makes the intention pretty clear.

Comment: In making it correct, you also made it way less efficient. I would pretty much can `groupby` and roll with a one pass solution at this point.